# React Material UI Expansion Panel disable cursor pointer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to disable the cursor hover in the Material-ui expansion panel so that the hover only appears on the ExpandIcon:

https://material-ui.com/api/expansion-panel/

I don't want to use the disabled property of ExpansionPanel but I can't find a way to control the cursor pointer behaviour via css in the ExpansionPanelSummary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changes the mouse have from pointer to default you can not  open the panel clicking on the panel but only clicking on the icon opens the summary pannel. [Check out sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-benz-chm6k?file=/src/Demo.jsx)

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ExpansionPanel from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel";
import ExpansionPanelSummary from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary";
import ExpansionPanelDetails from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    "& .MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root:hover": {
      cursor: "default"
    }
  },
  panel: {
    cursor: "default"
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
  }
}));

export default function SimpleExpansionPanel() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ExpansionPanel expanded={open}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} />}
          classes={{
            // if styles not ovverided it shows flickering
            root: classes.panel // class name, e.g. `classes-nesting-root-x`
          }}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Expansion Panel 1</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to do it using CSS. then add these lines to your CSS file and then import it. But you might see little flicker because after the default sets the cursor to the pointer you are changing it to default(arrow). You might override that in theme or with the make style and class prop.

```
.MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root:hover {
  cursor: "default";
}
```

Comment: MuiExpansionPanel has been updated to MuiAccordion. There is also an expand icon that will have a cursor pointer on hover as well. You can set the following to override both...


        '& .MuiAccordionSummary-root:hover, .MuiButtonBase-root:hover': {
          cursor: 'default',
        },

Answer (score 3):

MuiExpansionPanel has been updated to MuiAccordion. The AccordionSummary expand icon and the AccordionSummary will both have a cursor pointer on hover. You can set the following to override both...

```
'& .MuiAccordionSummary-root:hover, .MuiButtonBase-root:hover': {
  cursor: 'default',
},
```